# recursive function inside map is undefined

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
export const normaliseHistoryLog = history => {

    if (history.children.length === 0) {
        debugger;
        return {
            id: history.id,
            date: history.timestamp, 
            time: history.timestamp,
            event: history.event.label,
            eventHTML: getHTML(history.event.detail), 
            source: history.source,
            requestor: history.requestor
        }
    }
    debugger;
    return {
        id: history.id,
        date: history.timestamp, 
        detail: history.children.map(normaliseHistoryLog),
        time: history.timestamp,
        event: history.event.label,
        eventHTML: getHTML(history.event.detail), 
        source: history.source,
        requestor: history.requestor
    }
}
```

I get an error about this

```
detail: history.children.map(normaliseHistoryLog),
```

saying that 'normaliseHistoryLog' is undefined.

I have tried the following:

```
detail: history.children.map((el) => normaliseHistoryLog(el))
```

but still no luck.

The function is called:

```
export const getHistory = asyncMiddleware(async (req) => {
    const path = `url`;
    const response = await get(req, path);
    debugger;
    return response.result.map(normaliseHistoryLog);
});
```

where response.result is an array of objects

Comment: Please add some sample data and an example of how you call the function to the code to turn it into a complete [mcve]. You can use the live demo feature so people can run the code in the question itself.

Comment: @Quentin I think OP is trying to recursive map, i.e. they are passing the function itself as the callback.

Comment: @Li357 — Yes, it looks like they are. And a glance at the code makes it look like it should work, hence why I want a version that I can actually run and see what happens.

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR;**

```
function normaliseHistoryLog(history) {
    if (history.children.length === 0) {
        debugger;
        return {
            id: history.id,
            date: history.timestamp, 
            time: history.timestamp,
            event: history.event.label,
            eventHTML: getHTML(history.event.detail), 
            source: history.source,
            requestor: history.requestor
        }
    }
    debugger;
    return {
        id: history.id,
        date: history.timestamp, 
        detail: history.children.map(normaliseHistoryLog),
        time: history.timestamp,
        event: history.event.label,
        eventHTML: getHTML(history.event.detail), 
        source: history.source,
        requestor: history.requestor
    }}
    export function normaliseHistoryLog;
```

This is due to hoisting.
The way you declared the function `normaliseHistoryLog` is called function expression.
Function expressions (which is basically assigning functions as variables) even if they are exported, are done at a later stage.
What this means is that the function is not known (available) to be used when the closure is created (when you declare the function and assign it).

You can read more about it by looking up hoisting in JS.
for example here:
https://gomakethings.com/function-expressions-vs-function-declarations/